# Код в одну строчку. Подскажите синтаксис

Tags: python, python-3.x

На входе три числа, а, b, c три стороны четырёхугольника, надо найти периметр, если известно, что четвёртая сторона m = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^0.5

На входе даётся три числа:

```
3
4
12
```

На выходе:

32

```
print(int(input(a)) + int(input(b)) + int(input(c)) + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)
```

или

```
print(a = int(input()) + b = int(input()) + c = int(input()) + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)
```

Это неправильные примеры. Есть решение в две строки:

```
a, b, c, = map(int, input().split())
print(a + b + c + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)
```

Comment: `print((int(input("введите a:"))**2 + int(input("введите b:"))**2 + int(input("введите c:"))**2)**.5)` Но лучше так не делать - не хотел бы я увидеть такой код в проекте... ;)

Comment: То есть так: `print(int(input('a')) + int(input('b')) + int(input('c')) + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)`

Comment: Задание именно в одну строку.

Comment: В задании водится три цифры на трёх строчках.

Comment: 1. Считывать через пробел в одну строку. 2. Использовать split и reduce. 3. Использовать второй питон.

Comment: В две строки получается: a, b, c =int(input()),int(input()),int(input())                                     print = (a + b + c + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^0.5) А вот как воткнуть в одну строку ума не приложу!

Comment: @MaxU, ну у меня получилось в одну, но только под второй питон. Можно как-то от импорта в третьем избавиться?

Comment: `print((lambda a, b, c: a + b + c + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)(int(input()), int(input()), int(input())))`

Comment: @MaxU, всё, я сделал))

Comment: @andreymal, тоже интересный вариант - давай в ответы его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ideone.com/USELJ0

```
print((lambda a, b, c: a + b + c + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)(int(input()), int(input()), int(input())))
```

Comment: Получается, у нас два подхода, как любой код кроме импортов можно превратить в одну строку?)

Comment: @Qwertiy вот я тоже сейчас сижу и думаю, реально ли так написать конвертер любого кода в однострочник) Да и для импортов тоже `__import__('functools').reduce` есть)

Comment: Прикольно :) Интересно, а ещё есть способы?...

Comment: @Qwertiy ой, гугл говорит, что такой конвертер даже существует https://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Как то неправильно работает конвертер.

Comment: @Trulimon, у меня работает: https://ideone.com/KbVhmC. В качестве программы скормил ему `a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
print(a + b + c + (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**0.5)` Вот результат: `(lambda __g, __print: [[[(__print((((a + b) + c) + ((((a ** 2) + (b ** 2)) + (c ** 2)) ** 0.5))), None)[1] for __g['c'] in [(int(input()))]][0] for __g['b'] in [(int(input()))]][0] for __g['a'] in [(int(input()))]][0])(globals(), __import__('__builtin__', level=0).__dict__['print'])`

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3

Ввод в 3 строки: https://ideone.com/G4fPlS

```
print([sum(x) + sum(y**2 for y in x)**.5 for x in [[int(input()) for x in range(3)]]][0])
```

## Python 2

Ввод в одну строку: https://ideone.com/xMAUuC

```
print reduce(lambda s,s2: s+s2**.5, reduce(lambda r,x: [r[0]+x,r[1]+x*x], map(int,raw_input().split()), [0,0]))
```

Ввода в 3 строки: https://ideone.com/KQke8k

```
print reduce(lambda s,s2: s+s2**.5, reduce(lambda r,x: [r[0]+x,r[1]+x*x], [int(raw_input()) for x in range(3)], [0,0]))
```

Comment: Замечательно, и понятно. Спасибо.